# siunitx and adjectives

Tags: siunitx

I would like to know if the `siunitx` package offers the possibility of adding an adjective after the unit, to get a hyphenated compound adjective.

For instance, when typesetting "a 10 km-long road", I would like to pass the adjective as an optional argument to `\SI{1}{\kilo\meter}`, as in `\SI[[adj=long]{1}{\kilo\meter}`, instead of having to type `\SI{1}{\kilo\meter}-long`.

Please understand that there is nothing wrong with the `\SI{1}{\kilo\meter}-long` syntax. It just "feels" wrong to hyphenate a command with a word. Also, I think this would make corrections a bit more straightforward.

If this functionality is not offered, is it something the author of the package has thought of or is planning to implement?

Comment: What is wrong with `\SI{1}{\kilo\meter}-long`?

Comment: Almost certainly not the best way to write this: I would go for words in the example given.

Comment: Such a construction is typical in English, but it's completely extraneous to other languages such as Italian and French.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The only thing wrong with `\SI{1}{\kilo\meter}-long` is that you're hyphenating the command with a word. It just feels like bad practice. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @egreg I understand that. Actually, I'm not even sure this rule applies in british english. In a complete solution, I'd check for the `american` option of the `babel` package.

Comment: ISO 80000-1 sec. 7.2.1 says "any attachment to a unit symbol as a means of giving information about the special nature of the quantity or context of measurement under consideration is not permitted". So, I could be wrong, but I think you shoudn't attach anything to a unit symbol by means of a hyphen. There is an example here (http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf) where the term "long" is not attached to the unit symbol.

Comment: @Luigi Your comment actually answers my question. I remove the hyphens and forward the ISO document to the person responsible for validating the style of my thesis at my school so that I'm not penalized for that again.

Answer (score 2):

You could define your own macro:

```
\newcommand*\SIadj[4][]{\SI[#1]{#3}{#4}-#2}
```

and use it as

```
\SIadj{long}{1}{\kilo\metre}
```

If you want to prevent hypenations use

```
\newcommand*\SIadj[4][]{\mbox{\SI[#1]{#3}{#4}-#2}}
```

or

```
\newcommand*\SIadj[4][]{\SI[#1]{#3}{#4}\hbox{-}#2}
```